# How can i extract data in django template if multiple rows are sent to template containing multiple colums?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

sir I am trying to send multiple rows from a database containing multiple columns. Data is sent successfully to the HTML template in Django but when I tried to print particular columns of rows sent, data is not showing up. please help?
[image: views.py]
[image: template.py]
[[image: resulting page]]

Comment: show what you did so far

Comment: Post your code as text, not as images.

Comment: You should use Django ORM queries not raw sql. It will be easy to write and understand. FOr the isseue, check if data is stored in Restaurent model. Also csrf_token is for forms.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing what sort of data 'row' contains, is it a list containing dictionaries? I can see you create a list called 'l' which is then not used, it looks like you are trying to target the data you need with this list.

Without knowing what sort of data you have collected I would try in views;

```
return render(request,'searchresults.html',{"l":l})
```

Then in your template

```html
<table>
 {% for i in l %}
   <tr>
     <td>1.</td>
     <td>{{  i  }}
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```